# My App crashes when I try to use ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Whenever I try to implement the ArrayAdapter on my ListView in my MainActivity.kt file, my app crashes. Once I comment it out, my app is able to run but, of course, it doesn't display the list of names that I want it.

This hasn't given me an issue before and even Googling it hasn't given me much insight into the problem I'm facing. I'm  not sure if it may be caused due to me using Fragments as well as Activities. If anyone has any insights, it'd be greatly appreciated

main.kt:

```
package com.example.contactslist

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

/**
* A simple [Fragment] subclass.
*/
class main : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
}
}
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.contactslist

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ListView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var CONTACT_DETAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST = 0

val names = ArrayList<String>()
val numbers = ArrayList<Int>()
// Variable to hold relationships

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    names.add("Baraka")
    names.add("Blandy")
    numbers.add(732)
    numbers.add(666)

    val contactsAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_listview, names)
    val listView1 = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.contact_list)
    listView1.setAdapter(contactsAdapter)

    val add_new_contact = findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_contacts)

    add_new_contact.setOnClickListener {
        val name = ""
        val phone_number = 1
        val relationship = ArrayList<String>()

        val intent1 = Intent(this,ContactDetails::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent1, CONTACT_DETAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST)
    }
}
}
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".main">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contacts"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contact_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Delete"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Add"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    >
</Button>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.contactslist.main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/contact_list"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<!--    <CheckBox-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/checked"-->
<!--        android:checked="false"/>-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Here's the LogCat Error Log -

10-09 21:19:25.953 21333-21333/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-09 21:19:26.167 21333-21339/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
10-09 21:19:26.168 21333-21339/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
10-09 21:19:26.736 21333-21333/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.contactslist-1/lib/x86
10-09 21:19:27.245 21333-21333/com.example.contactslist W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-09 21:19:27.618 21333-21333/com.example.contactslist I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
10-09 21:19:27.618 21333-21333/com.example.contactslist I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
10-09 21:19:27.725 21333-21333/com.example.contactslist W/art: Verification of void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.dispatchFinishTemporaryDetach(android.view.View) took 103.153ms
10-09 21:19:27.972 21333-21343/com.example.contactslist I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2073(241KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 52% free, 925KB/1949KB, paused 1.940ms total 150.819ms
10-09 21:19:28.074 21333-21370/com.example.contactslist D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-09 21:19:28.268 21333-21333/com.example.contactslist E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
10-09 21:19:28.269 21333-21333/com.example.contactslist D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-09 21:19:28.271 21333-21333/com.example.contactslist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.contactslist, PID: 21333
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:393)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.create

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Comment: There is no Error when I run the App. The App only crashes once I try to open it in my emulated Android phone

Comment: _The App only crashes once I try to open it in my emulated Android phone_ share the crash report logs

Comment: Oh alright, I'll try to add in in to my original post in a bit. I just need to test for it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your crash in activity_listview.xml
replace

```
android:id="@+id/contact_name"
```

with

```
android:id="@android:id/text1"
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if it fixed your problem. If not please let me know so i could further look into it to help you. Thanks

Comment: I'll definitely try and implement it, albeit, I'm not sure why I should replace it with that. Could you explain why?

Comment: becoz ArrayAdapter need to use layout having TextView with id text1. It cannot detect your custom id. You can use custom ids with custom adapters.

Comment: Oh alright, I see. Hmm, in that case, would I be able to use a CheckBox alongside it as well? I need to also implement a CheckBox to delete the corresponding elements from the list after I click on the Delete Button

Comment: You need to make your custom adapter then which can extend ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter. You have complete control to include whatever you want in your list item layout in custom adapter.

Comment: Oh okay, gotcha. Yeah, that's more or less what I'm doing atm. It's just a bit tricky to deal with for when you want to deal with deleting your checked items

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this issues replace below line from your code.**

```
val contactsAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_listview, names)
```

**With**

```
val contactsAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names)
```

Comment: Wait, why should I use simple_list_item_1? I don't even recall defining that anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The crash is probably because the `ArrayAdpater` is expects a `TextView` but you passed a `LinearLayout`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.create
```

In your `activity_listview.xml` you need to remove the `LinearLayout` that wraps the `TextView`:

activity_listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: But I've previously used this exact same configuration elsewhere and ArrayAdapter didn't give me an issue for having my TextView in a LinearLayout

Comment: It does technically fix it but, then, I end up with my list overlapping over my TextView object, that I used as a title, despite the TextView object being defined above the ListView

Comment: @CodingPoding It sounds odd. How can a change in an list item layout influate the outer layout of the fragment?  Did you change anything else inside `fragment_main.xml`? Please update the attached code of `fragment_main.xml`

Comment: I didn't make any changes inside of the fragment_main.xml file

Comment: @CodingPoding Ok so because you are using `ConstraintLayout` you'll need to say that the `ListView` should be beneath the title `TextView`. On `fragment_main.xml`, give your `TextView` an id like: `android:id="@+id/title"` and then set the `LinearLayout` that wraps the `ListView` to the bottom of that title: `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Plus, trying to remove the LinearLayout gives me issues once I add in a CheckBox later on, for example. It's perhaps better I just use a custom array adapter

Comment: @CodingPoding You are right. For this matter you should use a custom `ArrayAdpater`. cheers.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help :)